# Refresh token issue for Connected App in 2GP Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, app, 2gp

I have an issue related to Connected App in 2GP managed package. I use OAuth 2.0 Web Server Flow for Web App Integration. I have 3 absolutely identical Connected Apps created on PBO edition org (no need to add them to package). One for Dev environments, second for Staging, Third for Production (Client has 3 environments for development of his app). Everything works perfect for Dev and Staging. As I collected all the stuff to a 2gp package, install it on scratch org and dev orgs, refresh tokens are not refreshed actually. The scope of connected app includes Refresh_token (in all other cases it works), the external service performs callout to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token and in response it always gets

> ```
> { 
>   "error": "invalid_grant",
>   "error_description": "expired access/refresh token" 
> }
> ```

In policies I set "refresh token is valid until revoked". The strangest thing is everything works well with two the same Connected Apps and fails with Prod one when we work with managed package.

Update: I deployed all the code to the new dev org (not a package, but simply the same components directly) and it all works via that connected app (for Prod). But on the org where I install a package, the external service can not refresh token and can't send any API requests to Salesforce.

Thank you very much for your help. Any ideas are appreciated!